# Missing page numbers

Tags: numbering, page-numbering, page

Please I have a problem in which the number of pages just appears for the first pages and the rest is disappeared? please it's urgent any suggestions?

[image]

The preamble of the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.6cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[nopostdot,  style=super, nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{leading}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfgantt} 
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}



\usepackage{booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tocstyle}


\usepackage{capt-of}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\usepackage{tocloft}%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}




%------------------------------------------------------
%Table

    \usepackage{enumitem, etoolbox, tabularx, makecell, booktabs}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
    \makeatother


%------------------------------------------------------



%\newcommand{\autodot}{.}

%----------------------------------------------------
%Add some level of subclasses
\newenvironment{subs}{\adjustwidth{2em}{0pt}}{\endadjustwidth}
\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]
\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]

\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph{\theparagraph.\arabic{subparagraph}}

\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{6}
\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{7em}{4em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{6em}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{subsubsubsection}{section}
\@addtoreset{subsubsubsection}{subsection}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}



%-----------------------------------------------------
%Space Before and After Sections and Subsections Titles 
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip}

%------------------------------------------------------
%Space Between Lines
\linespread{1.15}

%-------------------------------------------------------
%Bibliography
\usepackage[backend=biber ,bibstyle=ieee, citestyle=numeric, dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

%-------------------------------------------------------
% Rename the contents title
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Content}

   %Add dot after the section number




%-------------------------------------------------------
% Table caption
% \captionsetup[table]{skip=3pt}



%------------------------------------------------------
%Acronyms

\makeglossaries


\newglossaryentry{NB}{
name = NB,
description = Naïve Bayes
}




\overfullrule=0pt
\hypersetup{final}

%-------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Urgently provide us with some code that replicates the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Well, some `\pagestyle{empty}` around there in your code?

Comment: no, it was appear previously but I don't no what happened

Comment: What is the purpose of posting screenshots of warning messages that are not related to the problem?

Comment: @Werner I added the photo

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This is the thing appeared to me. I'm not sure if it will help

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228 If you want to solve this quickly, help us to help you and show use the code that causes the problem.

Comment: I added the preamble of the document, please tell me if there is something else needed.

Comment: @F505: The last line just before `\begin{document}` reads: `\pagestyle{empty}`. Remove that and give us some feedback.

Comment: @Werner Yesss Thank you so so much I couldn't describe my thankful for you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Page numbers are typically inserted as part of the page style. An `empty` page style removes both header and footer from your document, which is probably what happened here.

Remove `\pagestyle{empty}` from your code in order to restore the page numbering.